# VBScript to Powershell - Environment Variables

Tags: powershell, vbscript, powershell-2.0

I am currently working on a powershell script that maps directories along with loading database software.  I have this current vbscript I am converting to powershell that is suppose to validate a temporary file path , but I am getting a little confused on what I may need to take out and what I can leave in.

Here is the original ***vbscript*** ...

```
'
' assure that temp version of Perl is used
'
perlPath = basePath & "install\perl\bin;"
WshShell.Environment("Process")("PATH") = perlPath & WshShell.Environment("System")("PATH")
'
' assure that temp version of Perl Lib is used
'
perlLib = basePath & "\install\perl\lib;" & basePath & "\install\perl\site\lib;"
WshShell.Environment("Process")("PERL5LIB") = perlLib
```

Here is what I have written in ***powershell*** so far ...

```
#
# assure that Oracle's version of Powershell is used
# 
$psPath = $basePath + "install\powershell\bin;" 
$sysPath = $WshShell.Environment("System") | Where-Object { $_ -match "PATH" } | 
           foreach-object {$_.Substring(9)} | Out-String
$psPos = $sysPath.contains($psPath)
if( -not ($psPos)){
    [Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("PATH", ($psPath + $sysPath), "Process")  
} 
#
# assure that Oracle's version of Powershell Module is used
# 
$psMod =  $homePath + "\perl\lib;" + $homePath + "\perl\site\lib;" # still need to convert 
$sysMod = $Env:PSModulePath 
$psPos = $sysMod.contains($psMod)
if( -not ($psPos)){
    [Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("PATH", ($psPath + $sysChk), "Process")  
}}
```

The same validation is done later in the script with the "System" variables. I do have a module that I will be using, but the rest are scripts.  I guess I am not sure if what I am converting is the right way to verify these pathways exist and if not to add the new pathways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you should use the [Join-Path](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=113347) cmdlet for combining a path:

```
$psPath = Join-Path  $basePath "install\powershell\bin"
```

You can access the `Path`variable using `$env:Path` split it using `-split ';'` and select the first path entry using `[0]`. All in all, I would define the three path you want to set, put them into an array and iterate over it.

```
$powershellBin = Join-Path $basePath  "install\powershell\bin" 
$perLib = Join-Path $homePath "\perl\lib" 
$perlSiteLib = Join-Path $homePath "\perl\site\lib"

@($powershellBin, $perLib, $perlSiteLib) | foreach {
    if (-not (($env:Path -split ';')[0].Equals($_)))
     {
        [Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("PATH", ("{0};{1}" -f $_, $env:Path), "Process")
     }
 }
```

Comment: thanks for the great example! Didn't realize there was a `Join-Path` cmdlet in powershell.